# Problem in calling web service in Android

Tags: .net, android, web-services, json

I need working tutorial on it. I have tried some tutorial but all of them is giving error.

I am developing an Android app, I want some data for my app from server and also want to store some data on server. I don't want use any external library. Web service will be in .net only. I need tutorial for both for web service as well as how to access web service in Android. I'm using json over HTTPClient.  Can anyone help me?

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
URI uri = new URI("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=youraddress&sensor=true");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
    out.close();

    json = new JSONObject(out.toString());
}
```